# access to week days in mysql database using python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a table in my MySQL database which looks like this:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| mon  | tue  | wed  | thu  | fri  | sat  | sun  |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 1    | 1    | 1    | 1    | 1    | 0    | 1    |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

I will connect to this database using Python. I  have created an access to the table above using binary numbers.

My question is:
When for example, it is Saturday(time now) and in my database I see the number **1** or **0**.
 when it is **1** my output is: `print('access')`
 and if it is **0** `print('no access')`.

Comment: Why not make a query that, based on the day-of-week queries a certain column. Normally you make selections on rows, not that much on columns.

Comment: i can't implement this,please help me

Comment: To expand on @WillemVanOnsem's comment, it would be a lot more natural to have just two columns in the database, `day` and `access`. 
 Then put seven rows in the database, one for each day.  Then you could have a query like `SELECT access FROM mytable WHERE day = 'sat'`

Comment: but i have anothers columns in my database.